# How to use norm.ppf with a loc, scale and x as numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, statistics, vectorization

I am using scipy.stats.norm package to calculate CDF and ICDF. I want to pass loc and scale parameter as numpy array and want result for same number of x values. The norm.cdf function is returning good result (see below):

```
>>> norm.cdf([0.1, 0.2, 0.3], loc = [2, 3, 4], scale = [0, 1, 2])
array([        NaN,  0.00255513,  0.03215677])
```

While norm.ppf function for finding ICDF is giving me error:

```
>>> norm.ppf([0.1, 0.2, 0.3], loc = [2, 3, 4], scale = [0, 1, 2])
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#16>", line 1, in <module>
    norm.ppf([0.1, 0.2, 0.3], loc = [2, 3, 4], scale = [0, 1, 2])
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\distributions.py", line 718, in ppf
    output = valarray(shape(cond),value=self.a*scale + loc)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\distributions.py", line 235, in valarray
    out = reshape(repeat([value],product(shape,axis=0),axis=0),shape)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 152, in reshape
    return reshape(newshape, order=order)
ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged
```

I dont want to loop through it multiple times as my number of loc, scale and x values are large in number.
Could you please help me to solve this with numpy vectorization? Many thanks:)

Comment: Cannot reproduce in Python 3.6 with SciPy 1.1.0 and NumPy 1.15.4, I get just a couple of warnings ("invalid value encountered in multiply") and the result `array([       nan, 2.15837877, 2.95119897])`.

Comment: Thanks buddy!!! I got it.. It's the issue with my python version (2.6.5). I have tried it on online python tools, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're modeling with zero variance but you weren't getting "good results" for either setup. It's just that one triggered a brasher error message than the other. The reason they both gave you error messages was because of your zero variance. This isn't about a version of Python not working right. It's about the statistics. Try this:

```
scipy.stats.norm.ppf([0.1, 0.2, 0.3], loc = [2, 3, 4], scale = [0.01, 1, 2])
```

A homoscedastic application: Consider an array of speed measurements, l_speed, being fitted with a normal distribution. This example leads to a Q-Q plot to test how well the measurement error fits a normal dis'n.

```
loc = l_speed.mean()
scale = l_speed.std()

# or alternatively
# loc, scale = scipy.stats.norm.fit(l_speed)

l_rv = stats.norm(loc, scale)     # models normal dis'n for one random variable each time it is called

x = np.array([np.percentile(l_speed.p) for p in np.linspace(0,100,20))
y = np.array([l_rv.ppf(p) for p in np.linspace(0.0001,1.0,20)])
plt.plot(x,y,linestyle='None', marker='o', color='blue')
plt.plot([550,1000],[550,1000],color='red', linestyle='--', linewidth=1)
plt.xlabel('Empirical Data')
plt.ylabel('Normal Distribution');
```